# Redirect 404 to external domain, preserving URI, using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, errordocument

Spent a while on this and searched a lot. Found questions and answers that almost covered what I need, but not quite...

In a nutshell: Trying to redirect a user to an external domain when they receive a 404, preserving the URI, **using only .htaccess**.

Considerations:

- Apache does not know of the files on the server, it requests them dynamically from a CMS.
- The requested URI *may* have funky characters in it, e.g. ";" "="
- Need to avoid any server side scripting (e.g. php).

Required behaviour:

- User requests a URL
- Server responds with a 404
- User is transparently redirected to an external domain, preserving the URI

> Example 1:
>
> - User requests: www.example.com/no/Page
> - Server responds with 404
> - User is redirected to: www.newdomain.com/no/Page
>
> Example 2:
>
> - User requests: www.example.com/url;=xyz
> - Server responds with 404
> - User is redirected to: www.newdomain.com/url;=xyz

Can this be implemented **only** with .htaccess?

Trying something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html?u=/the/Requested/URI

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^u=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com%1? [NC,NE,L,R=301,E=nocache:1]
```

This mostly works, but only with the hardcoded query string... can't get it included dynamically.

Any ideas how to achieve this (if at all)?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with [`ErrorDocument`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#errordocument), e.g.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Unfortunately this works only with Apache >= 2.4.13

> From 2.4.13, expression syntax can be used inside the directive to produce dynamic strings and URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, just one additional note: if trying to redirect to an external URL with status code 401, it will not work. It's explained in the official Apache doc : "In addition, if you use a remote URL in an ErrorDocument 401, the client will not know to prompt the user for a password since it will not receive the 401 status code. Therefore, if you use an ErrorDocument 401 directive, then it must refer to a local document."